# CMS for job website

Tags: cms

What is the best CMS (content management system) I can use in the development of a job portal?

Can Plone be used for something like this?

Comment: why did you ask this twice?

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! [What's "best" is always subjective](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/157/185): *one man's owl is another man's nightingale.* Better describe what would make this software *fitting best for you* – which then enables us to give fitting recommendations. See [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) for more hints. Then **[edit]** your post accordingly (do *not* repost the question).

Answer (score 1):

"Best" depends on who you would ask, but iMO you should definitely consider [Drupal](https://www.drupal.org/) as part of your shortlist.

You would have all sorts of options to complete your implementation using out-of-the-box facilities (i.e zero custom coding ...) with contributed modules (disclosure: my favorite ones ...) such as:

- [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views).
- [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules).
- [Flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag).
- [Message](https://www.drupal.org/project/message).
- [Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/group).