# Content Management system i can use for a Job Website

Tags: php, cms

What is the best CMS (Content management system) I can use in the development of a job portal, been thinking of a good one i can use, Can plone be used for something like this?

Comment: Are you aware that you posted this question twice? Better delete [the other one](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/42579/content-management-system-i-can-use-for-a-job-website)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend Drupal, simply because its extremely easy to setup, easy to use, has an awesome front-end and tons of contributed modules to help you.

Just Google for Drupal Job Portal and you will get lot of helpful links. Here is one of them: [Create a job portal website using Drupal](https://prakashdrupal.wordpress.com/2014/03/07/create-a-job-portal-website-using-drupal-part-i/)